# XDebug (2.9.8) not able to find breakpoint in VSCode (PHP 7.4.11)

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

When running Xdebug on VSCode and setting a breakpoint, Xdebug interrupts code execution but doesn't seem to be able to point to the line where the breakpoint was set.
The affected PHP function is properly listed in the  call stack.

[image: call stack screenshot]

But neither is the affected line in the code highlighted nor am I given the option to continue code execution in the debug menu. Step over, step into, step out are all greyed out.

I run this on localhost.

My Xdebug environment was running perfectly until I recently upgraded my XAMPP environment to the latest PHP 7.4.11 and Xdebug to the matching version 2.9.8 (as recommended by the Xdebug page).

php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.default_enable=1
```

VSCode: launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not 100% reproduceable.
First it happend in 8 out of 10 cases, then it seemed that only one vue project was affected and the other only showed the error in 2 out of 10 cases.
Then I updated dependencies with npm and compared all configuration files, but didn't find any differences between those two projects.
Since today everything seems to work again.
I can only guess that this is a timing issue. VScode or Xdebug seem to need some time to establish the connection and the proper mapping between the apache server an VScode.

In any case - case closed.